# Fastlane: how to automate getting login session for Apple ID?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, fastlane

My question is how to automate getting login session for Apple ID with fastlane in Jenkins's pipeline?

According to documentation, at first I should manually execute such command

`fastlane spaceauth -u user@email.com`

and then paste the session value to FASTLANE_SESSION environment variable in pipeline.

But I don't want to make it manually all the time. How to automate this process ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to add this row in pipeline script, before invoking fastlane

```
export FASTLANE_PASSWORD=your_password
```

So after, fastlane was able to login in Apple